# SQL Request to Doctrine 2 QueryBuilder

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

i'm new with symfony and Doctrine 2

i have a SQL query i made

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE(history.played_at), '%m-%Y') AS 'date' , 
       COUNT(DISTINCT(l.id)) AS 'value'
FROM listeners AS l LEFT JOIN history ON history.listener_id = l.id
WHERE history.played_at IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY YEAR(DATE(history.played_at)), WEEK(DATE(history.played_at))
```

I want to use it in my symfony project using Doctrine 2 and the QueryBuilder but i can't find how to do it

i currently have this

```
$qb->select($qb->expr()->countDistinct('l.id'))
       ->from('AppBundle:Listener', 'l')
       ->leftJoin('AppBundle:History', 'h', 'l.id = h.listener')
       ->where($qb->expr()->isNotNull('h.played_at'));
```

but it doesn't work at all and a lot of things are missing

could be really nice if someone can show me clearly how to do it

Comment: You might have to use a raw query here.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes that's what i wanted but we will soon maybe move on PostGreSQL then i need to it with the QueryBuilder

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen if there is not other way to do it i will use a raw query but if it's possible to do it with Query Builder from Doctrine i want to do it with it. The problem is I have no idea how to do it

Comment: First fix your query.  You should be grouping by the `DATE_FORMAT` expression, the same as what you select.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the query is valid

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen and it gives me the result I want; it doesn't answer my question

Comment: `the query is valid` ... the query may _run_, but that does not make it logically correct.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen the query runs, in less than 1s, gives me all the results I want. My question is how to do it in PHP with Doctrine and not how cool is my SQL request which do exactly do what i want

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen then you think i should use a raw query ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141564/discussion-between-rommer-and-tim-biegeleisen).

Comment: I don't have any more to say.  Clean up the SQL, then just use a raw query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not an SQL expert, but this query should work :

```
        $qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('COUNT(DISTINCT l.id)')
        ->from('AppBundle:Listener', 'l')
        ->leftJoin('AppBundle:History', 'h')
        ->where('h.playet_at IS NOT null');
```

If you want to go further, i recommend you to see the Doctrine Query Builder Doc
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html

Hope this helps

**Edit** : WEEKS is not native in Doctrine but you can use it with https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions